# Deleting Portion of String While Accessing URL Paths Swift

Tags: swift

I'm currently trying to create a list of songs at the path 
"/Music/Itunes/iTunes Media/Music" to eventually insert them into the Youtube API.
I can access all the desired files. I'm just looking for a way to clean up the printed items, as seen below, the album name is in front of the Song name.

```
var test = try FileManager.default.subpathsOfDirectory (atPath: completePath)

let list = test.joined(separator: "\n")
// Attempt to delete album name  
print(list.replacingOccurrences(of: "/\(String())/" , with: ""))
```

this prints

```
J. Cole/2014 Forest Hills Drive
J. Cole/2014 Forest Hills Drive/12 Love Yourz.mp3
J. Cole/2014 Forest Hills Drive/06 Fire Squad.mp3
J. Cole/2014 Forest Hills Drive/09 No Role Modelz.mp3
```

is there a way to delete that portion? in order to return example 
"J. Cole 12 Love Yourz.mp3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, you should use `URL`s rather than paths to refer to files. So, instead of `subpathsOfDirectory`, use `FileManager`'s `enumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:)`. The enumerator returned by this method will give you a `URL` for each subpath within the directory. Unfortunately, `DirectoryEnumerator` is a bit Objective-C-ish in its interface, meaning that its element is `Any` instead of `URL` like you'd expect, but you can nonetheless access its `URL`s like this:

```
for each in enumerator {
    guard let eachURL = each as? URL, eachURL.pathExtension == "mp3" else { continue }

    let trackName = eachURL.lastPathComponent
    let albumName = eachURL.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent().lastPathComponent

    print("\(albumName) \(trackName)")
}
```

Then, you can just use `URL`'s `lastPathComponent` property to get just the filename without the rest of the path. Do the same for the directory representing the album, and you can stitch together the album name and track name to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to filter and combine the paths you obtain from `subpathsOfDirectory`:

```
var test = try FileManager.default.subpathsOfDirectory (atPath: completePath)

var list = test.flatMap {
    let pathComps = $0.components(separatedBy: "/")
    return pathComps.count >= 3 ? pathComps[0] + " " + pathComps.last! : nil
}.joined(separator: "\n")

print(list)
```

Output:

> J. Cole 12 Love Yourz.mp3
>   J. Cole 06 Fire Squad.mp3
>   J. Cole 09 No Role Modelz.mp3